# A row of a matrix and its reversed in the same matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, reverse, na

Is there any way to find if a row of a matrix is containing in the matrix but in the reversed way?

For example, this happens in the following matrix `W`:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
  [1,]    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3    3
  [2,]    1    2    3    1    2    3    1    2    3
  [3,]    3    3    3    2    2    2    1    1    1
```

between the first and the third row.

I have developed the following code, but it works ONLY if a row exists in the matrix in the reversed way:

```
WW=W[, rev(seq_len(ncol(W)))]

x=match(data.frame(t(W)), data.frame(t(WW)))
A=cbind( c(1:nrow(W)),x )

Z=t(apply(A,1,sort)) 

x=unique(Z[,2])
W=W[-x,]
```

So, in the previous matrix `W`, my code does not work, because of `NA` in the result of the second row of the code.

How can we solve this problem?

Comment: It's unclear what the last few lines are supposed to do. You seem to be able to find which rows are reversed or not, so your error appears to be something different from your written question (i.e. is there any way to find if a row is a reversed duplicate).

Comment: @Axeman, I want to put out the rows of the matrix that are the reversed of some others. This is what I do in the code from the third line till the last one.

Comment: Ok, so `W[!is.na(x), ]` will give the rows that have a reverse in the same matrix.

Comment: @Axeman That's correct, but I want to keep one row from each pair of rows. With pair, I mean a row and its reversed.

Answer (score 1):

"Is there any way to find if a row of a matrix is containing in the matrix but in the reversed way?"

Yes, calculate the distance between rows. If your matrix is not that huge, this is quite efficient:

```
m <- matrix(c(1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1), nrow = 3)
res <- as.matrix(dist(rbind(m, 
                            m[, rev(seq_len(ncol(m)))])))
res <- res[nrow(m) + seq_len(nrow(m)), seq_len(nrow(m))]
rownames(res) <- seq_len(nrow(m))

which(!res, arr.ind = TRUE)
#  row col
#3   3   1
#1   1   3

any(!res)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: It works but the problem is, as you said, that I have huge matrices.

Comment: What is "huge"? Your approach, even if you can fix it, won't scale well either. I would write a function with Rcpp if this is too slow.

Comment: I have matrices with 300.000 rows and maybe more.

Comment: As I said, a job for Rcpp (and even then it won't be fast). Have you calculated how many combinations of rows you want to check there? The number is staggering.

Comment: The rows of the matrices will be more than 300.000. In each case that I will study, the number of rows will be getting bigger and bigger.

Comment: Yes, time to polish your C++ skills (or any compiled language) and get access to a cluster with many CPUs.